# Connect android emulator to Vmware guest

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, vmware

My host system is Linux and I have Android SDK installed, so I am able to run Google's Android emulators with reasonable performance.
Now I need to develop some Xamarin app on Windows with VisualStudio. I have it installed on Vmware (Player), guest is Windows 7.

However, emulator's performance on my guest is terrible. So I decided to try to use emulator on my host Linux system and make it visible from guest. I guess I can connect it via network, but how to make it? Maybe could make ssh tunnel from hust to host with putty to access emulator running on host and simply use `adb connect` on guest to make emulator visible in Visual Studio.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

@user1209216 I've managed to do that using genymotion. I've connected the emulator to vmnet8, connect linux host to vmnet8 also and selected NAT on the vmware machine. Find the emulator's IP from Settings -> About Device menu, open VS in the vmware machine, open SDK command from VS Tools Menu and type "adb connect ip" using the ip of the emulator. The VS should recognize the emulator as external device. That is all.